# Entity Framework creating another column for One to One Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I have the following model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public int? StudentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I have two One to One relationships between Student and ApplicationUser, so in ModelCreating I defined the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOptional(u => u.Student)
                .WithRequired(s => s.User);
```

When the database is generated everything is fine except for the column name, I expect the created column in student to be UserId, but it creates the column UserId as a simple column, and creates another column User_Id for the relationship.

How can I define that property UserId in Student is the property for the relationship?

Comment: I don't think your entities are configured correctly...  Either Student has to come off ApplicationUser, or User has to come off Student...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is have an explicitly defined and mapped foreign key, it would look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasOptional(u => u.Student)
            .WithRequired(s => s.User)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);
```

if you don't explicitly specify, then an auto-generated foreign key is created following the naming convention of `[{PropertyName}_Id]`

Comment: is there anyway to configure that vía annotations, or is it only possible with fluent api?

Comment: @Escobar5 you may try adding [Key] and [ForeignKey("User ")] just on top of UserId ?

Comment: "if you don't explicitly specify, then an auto-generated foreign key is created following the naming convention of [{PropertyName}_Id]" thats not entirely true. the convention in one-to-one relations is to use the PK's of both entities. Only because there is the second relationship (CreatedBy), one needs to be specified or else it will follow this naming convention because it is implicitly a one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate which foreign key goes with which navigation property:

```
public class Student : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public string CreatedById { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships